# Question on integrating probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables with distribution functions $F_X,F_Y$. I need to show that $$P(Y\leq y+X)=\int F_Y(y+x)\mathrm{d}F_X(x)$$

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: $P(Y\leq y+X)=F_Y(y+X)$ does not make sense; the l.h.s. is a real number, and the r.h.s. is a random variable.

Comment: Sure you need an independence assumption.

Comment: More information is needed: independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

If the CDF of $\left(X,Y\right)$ is $F_{X,Y}$ then:
$$P\left(Y\leq y+X\right)=\iint f\left(u,v\right)dF_{X,Y}\left(u,v\right)$$
where $f$ sends $\left(u,v\right)$ to $1$ if $v\leq y+u$ and to
$0$ otherwise.

By independence of $X$ and $Y$ we have $F_{X,Y}\left(u,v\right)=F_{X}\left(u\right)F_{Y}\left(v\right)$
resulting in: $$\iint f\left(u,v\right)dF_{X,Y}\left(u,v\right)=\iint f\left(u,v\right)dF_{Y}\left(v\right)dF_{X}\left(u\right)=\int F_{Y}\left(y+u\right)dF_{X}\left(u\right)$$

I deliberately used $u$ and $v$ instead of $x$ and $y$ to avoid confusion that can rise because in your question $y$ is already used as a constant.

Comment: Thank you for very clear explanation. Would if we depart from independence. Will we have $P(Y\leq y+X) = \int F_Y(y+u)dF_{X|Y}(x|y)$, where $F_{X|Y}$ is a cdf of conditional distribution $X|Y$?

Comment: $P\left(Y\leq y+X\right)=\int P\left(Y\leq y+X\mid X=x\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)=\int F_{Y\mid X=x}\left(y+x\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)$.

Comment: And $F_{Y|X=x}(y+x) = \int_{-\infty}^{y+x}\frac{f_{YX}(u,x)}{f_X(x)}du$?

Comment: Yes, that looks good. On condition off course that there is a PDF.